How to check the multiple $refs in yaml schema using jsonschemavalidator in python
I have a Yaml api schema saved in a local file, C:/Users/test/api.yaml, a schema(AppSettings) in that is having multiple references where the references are existing in same file, but I'm not able to validate the schema against the instance due to its multiple references.
    AppSettings:
      type: object
      properties:
        default_language:
          type: string
          description: default language
        logo_image:
          allOf:
            - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Image'
            - type: object
              properties:
                width:
                  type: integer
                height:
                  type: integer
        user_configurations:
             $ref: '#/components/schemas/UserConfig'

    Image:
      type: object
      properties:
        url:
          type: string

UserConfig:
      type: object
      properties:
        authentication_providers:
          type: array
          items:
            $ref: '#/components/schemas/AuthenticationProvider'
        authentication_screens:
          type: object
          properties:
            login:
              type: integer
            register:
              type: integer  

AuthenticationProvider:
      type: object
      properties:
        provider:
          type: string
          enum:
            - auth0
            - telequebeq
        auth_type:
          type: string
          enum:
            - openid_connect
            - pairing
        auth_endpoint:
          type: string

When i simply try to validate the schema using validate(insctance, schema) its giving below error,
I have no idea how to implement this
jsonschema.exceptions._WrappedReferencingError: PointerToNowhere: '/components/schemas/Image' does not exist
